# purpose of enabled(true) or enabled(false) in a constructor in C++ class

Tags: c++11, constructor

what is the purpose of enabled(true) or enabled(false) in a constructor in C++ ?

```
    class A  
    {  
        public:  
        A() : enabled(true) {}  
        // body  
    };
```

Comment: This code does not compile.

Comment: The purpose is hard to discern, it hides behind the `//body` comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, it initializes a member `bool enabled;` to the value `true` when an object of type `A` is created without arguments given to the constructor.

Comment: @M.B. You can mark the question as resolved by clicking the check mark at the left of this answer.